# hydro's desktop-full

Tags: ros, desktop-full, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Heya,

I'm trying to build the full ros-hydro system according to the instructions [in the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Source).
When I try to run the rosinstall_generator for desktop-full:

```
$ rosinstall_generator desktop-full --rosdistro hydro --deps
```

this only tells me:

> The following not released packages/stacks will be ignored: desktop-full
> No packages/stacks left after ignoring not released

Why is desktop-full not released (yet?)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78601/hydro%27s-desktop-full/) by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2950 on 2013-09-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All variants have been replaced with metapackages in Hydro. Therefore they now do follow the ROS naming conventions which uses underscores instead of hyphen.

The following command works for me:

```
$ rosinstall_generator desktop_full --rosdistro hydro --deps
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ike](https://answers.ros.org/users/5431/ike/) on 2013-09-13**:
This solved my problem when I was trying to upgrade to hydra, thank you.  Could someone possibly edit the install page of the wiki to reflect this?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-09-13**:
I have updated the wiki page. Please feel free to make changes to the wiki yourself in the future if you are sure about the modifications.

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-04-27**:
amazing ! saved my day!